# What's the best way to handle automated data transformation and reporting. SSIS? SQL & Excel?

Tags: excel, ssis

**Background:**

I currently run reporting on a monthly basis from a source csv file that's roughly 50 columns by 15k rows. I have an existing system where I am importing the data into sql, using multiple stored procedures to handle the data transformations, then using excel connections to view the reports in excel after the data transformations. These transformations are relatively complex and comprise of ~4 stored procedures at ~5 pages and around 200 lines of code each.

---

**Problem:**

The amount of code and tables in sql to handle the transformations is becoming overwhelming. QA is a pain in the ass to track trough all the tables and stored procedures to find out where the problem lies. This whole process including extensive QA is taking me 3 days to complete, where ideally I'd like to to take half a day total. I can run through all the stored procedures and excel connections/formatting in a few hours, but currently it's more efficient to run QA after every single step.

**Potential Solutions:**

- Would integrating SSIS help the automation and QA process?
- I am new to SSIS, so how does data transformations work with SSIS?
- Do I just link a stored proc as a step in the SSIS flow?

**Note:** I should specify that the results need to be displayed in Excel on a heavily formatted worksheet. Currently, there is a feeder sheet in excel that fetches data from SQL views, and the report page has formula links to that feeder sheet.

I appreciate all the help in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I've done something similar and partially converted a SQL stored procedure (SP) solution to SSIS.

You can call existing SPs using the SSIS Execute SQL Task, so I would start with an SSIS "Master" package that just executes all your SPs.  Right out of the box that gives you control over dependancies, parallel execution, restartability & logging.

Then I would incrementally chip away at replacing the SPs with SSIS Data Flow Tasks - this opens up the full range of SSIS transformation capabilities and is almost always a lot faster to build and run than SPs.

I would replace the Excel layer with an Report Services Report, but this would probably be a lower priority.